# jquery ajax execute on all pages except one

Tags: ajax, symfony

I have an ajax request that gets the cart totals and display it on the page. It executes on every page except one.

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/load/get',
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#cart > button').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#cart > button').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {

            // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
            }, 100);

            $('#cart > ul').load('/load/totals ul li');

        }
    });
});
```

I have checked firebug and crome dev tools and it just shows that the request didn't run.

Are there any other tools I could use to find the problem?

Comment: was there any console errors in your chosen dev tools? Are the headers being sent correct?

Comment: No there are nun. On every page it shows Status: 200 Ok for the ajax request but on the one page it doesn't load the ajax request.

Comment: Console.log the return data, and add the error function to your ajax (console.log that as well), this might give you more information

Comment: I found the problem. I have never seen something like this. In my css I had a class (.product-main-image {margin-bottom: 0;cursor: zoom-in; cursor: -webkit-zoom-in; cursor: -moz-zoom-in}. For some unexplained reason it stopped the ajax from executing. I changed the name to  .product-main-imagex and everything is working.